# Phpstorm giving warnings while using prepare and get_results method with global variable $wpdb

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

[image]

I'm calling `$wpdb->prepare()` into a plugin as shown in screenshot.Although the code is running just fine but i'm wondering why phpstorm is giving warnings while wordpress support is enable in phpstorm.

Is there any way to remove these warnings but not hiding them from phpstorm settings?

Comment: Because it does not know of what type `$wpdb` variable is. Please try this (worked for me): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17766#comment=27-791847

Answer (score 2):

```
/** @var wpdb $wpdb */
global $wpdb;
```

By defining variable type, i removed all warnings in phpstorm related to `$wpdb`.
Thanks @LazyOne

[image]